# How to filter repeater on checkboxes checked value using jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-ajax

I am using asp.net webforms.

How can I filter a repeater based on the checked values of multiple checkboxes using jQuery?

The result will be if I chose any categories and cities it will dynamically display all the galleries under those categories/cities.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a682m.png)

I used repeater for categories and cites.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX2r8.png)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nXuD.png)

And repeater for galleries.

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wou73.png)

[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmyqg.png)

Comment: Please, post your code as [text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), not as images

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want that as soon as you check a checkbox, that it updates the UI?  In Web Forms, it gets pretty complicated, but you could attack it in different ways:

- Wrap the whole repeater and filter checkboxes in an UpdatePanel

  - Set AutoPostBack="True" on the checkbox, which triggers a postback, and as long as the checkbox AND repeater is in the UpdatePanel, it will appear pretty dynamically
- Or don't use an UpdatePanel, and let a postback happen
- Don't use a repeater, use a framework like JQuery and find a client-side way to render this (a jQuery templating framework), and use a web service on the backend that jQuery calls.  That is a pretty significant change and something I can't provide a lot of guidance in a single post but you can find a lot of online examples that do that.

ASP.NET MVC is more powerful for this because you can easily swap out/in different partial views, but it can work in web forms.  It just depends on how powerful it needs to be.